# Problems with non-self hosted web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl, soap

I'm trying to make a request to a Web service which is not self-hosted, in other words: an external part is hosting the service and has an open interface towards it.

I've generated a C# class from the wsdl using the svcutil on the service:
https://www.bt.bglinkws.bgonline.se/WebService/BgLinkService.svc

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// 



    public static void IgnoreBadCertificates()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
    }

    private static bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Application started");
        BgLinkServiceClient client = new BgLinkServiceClient();
        LogonRequest request = new LogonRequest();
        LogonResponse lg = new LogonResponse();


        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to connect to the Service...");
        IgnoreBadCertificates(); // Ignore certificate
        lg = client.Logon(request);

        //String autoStartToken = lg.Response.AutoStartToken;
        //Console.WriteLine("kolla");
        //Console.WriteLine(autoStartToken);


        client.Close();

    }


}
}
```

First I got this error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'example.com'. (the www is just an example)

My first guess was that the service is not issued by a trusted certificate authority.

Then I got a tip from a colleague to use the IgnoreBadCertificates method.

After that, I try to call the request again and I get this error:
SOAP security negotiation with '.svc link'(link to the service) for target '.svc link'(link to the service) failed. See inner exception for more details."

I'm quite new to Web services in general, but I can't really find a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bindings are correct, it could be that the service is not allowing SSL 3 or older TLS versions. Try this on your `ServicePointManager`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls || SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 || SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: I tried them all. I still get SOAP security negotiation with '.svc link'(link to the service) for target '.svc link'(link to the service) failed. See inner exception for more details."

Comment: Then I would concentrate on your bindings.